# Xamarin Android call a Fragment inside a Fragment

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, fragment

I have some problems with my Code. I'm trying to call a Fragment inside of a Tab Fragment.

So I have my Mainactivity, where i can create tabs like this:

```cs
private void initVp(ViewPager viewPager)
{
    var pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);

    pagerAdapter.addFragment(new customFragment1(), new Java.Lang.String("Frag1"));
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(new CustomFragment2(), new Java.Lang.String("Frag2"));

    viewPager.Adapter = pagerAdapter;
}
```

In my CustomFragment2 I have a Listview with Items:

```cs
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    root = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomFragment2, container, false);

    var adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this.Context, myList);

    listView = root.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);

    listView.Adapter = adapter;
    listView.ItemClick += showDetail;

    return root;
}

void showDetail(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    // What I have to do here?
}
```

I want to show the details of the Item that I clicked on in a new Fragment under the "Frag2" tab.
So how can I "replace" or show that details fragment under my tab instead of CustomFragment2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this working you will have to make a few changes in your code.

First, the ViewPager has to be moved from the Activity (MainActivity) to a Fragment, call it RootTabFragment or whatever you like.

In your MainActivity you will create an instance of this RootTabFragment:

```
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        var rootFragment = new RootTabFragment ();

        SupportFragmentManager
            .BeginTransaction ()
            .Add (Resource.Id.containerLayout, rootFragment)
            .Commit ();
    }
```

`Resource.Id.containerLayout` is just a FrameLayout in my Main.xml layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/containerLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

As previously indicated your ViewPager needs to be moved to a Fragment. Here you will do all the Tab logic as you had it in your MainActivity before.

```
    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.RootTabFragment, container, false);

        var pager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager> (Resource.Id.viewPager);

        var tabLayout = view.FindViewById<TabLayout> (Resource.Id.tabs);

        var adapter = new PagerAdapter (ChildFragmentManager);

        adapter.AddFragment (new customFragment1 (), "Fragment A");

        adapter.AddFragment (new customFragment2 (), "Fragment B");

        pager.Adapter = adapter;

        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager (pager);

        return view;
    }
```

There's a little change if you get to notice it, we are not gonna use the `SupportFragmentManager` instead we will use the `ChildFragmentManager`. You don't have to do any change in your Adapter class as both classes derived from **`FragmentManager`**.

**Note**: I am using a TabLayout in this example but you are good to remove that part of the code if you don't need it.

Now in your customFragment2 class

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    root = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomFragment2, container, false);

    var adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this.Context, myList);

    listView = root.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);

    listView.Adapter = adapter;
    listView.ItemClick += showDetail;

    return root;
}

void showDetail(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Activity
        .SupportFragmentManager
        .BeginTransaction ()
        .Replace (Resource.Id.containerLayout, new FragmentYouWantToNavigateTo ())
        .AddToBackStack(null)
        .Commit ();
}
```

This will replace the whole content of your `Resource.Id.containerLayout` which is in your MainActivity layout with your `FragmentYouWantToNavigateTo` which is the Fragment you want to show when clicking on one of the ListView items.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer!!! I can't actually use ChildFragmentManager because in my adapter i use Android.support.v4.App. So there are converting problems. maybe i have to change some code in my adapter? EDIT: I just have to use Android v4 in fragment... sry for that

Comment: In this example I also used Android.Support.V4.App. Just make sure your Adapter constructor takes as a parameter a `FragmentManager` not a `SupportFragmentManager` so this way you can use the `ChildFragmentManager`.

Comment: Thanks, this works so far, but if i click on an item , the tabs are gone + if i press hardware back button my App crashes. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Yeah, this code will make your tabs be replaced with your new Fragment view. What's the error you receive when pressing the back button?

Comment: Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: This can means many things but let me try to guess: your MainActivity should derive from `FragmentActivity`

Like this:

`public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136054/discussion-between-apineda-and-korken55).